# Как сделать три блока в одной линии с разным позиционированием?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap4

Как сделать что бы в коде снизу блок `TextTWO` отображался в середине всей линии, при этом ничего не убегало на следующую строчку. То есть нужен примерно такой вид:

`Контент справа|Контент центрального блока                                |контент слева`

А у меня получается вот такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И еще проблема в том, TextTWO как бы прилипает к TextONE даже если я указываю `margin` с помощью бутстрап класса `ml-3`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card-footer text-muted py-1">
  <div class="float-left">TextONE</div>
  <div class="">TextTWO</div>
  <div class="float-right">TextTHREE</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы подключаете 4-й бутстрап, забудьте про флоаты - теперь надо использовать возможности флекс-боксов. И, в отличие от 3-й версии, ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО оборачивать колонки в .row - иначе просто ничего не будет работать:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card-footer text-muted py-1">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2">TextONE</div>
  <div class="col-8" style="text-align: center">TextTWO</div>
  <div class="col-2" style="text-align: right">TextTHREE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: у вас совсем не то  что надо автору

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, а что надо автору?

Comment: там на скрине посмотрите - два блока слева и один блок с права

Answer (score -1):

зачем тебе флоаты если ты используешь бутстрап, просто пиши каждому col-xs-4, а среднему text-align: center;

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card-footer text-muted py-1">
  <div class="col-xs-4">TextONE</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">TextTWO</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">TextTHREE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: в 4-м бутстрапе нет классов .col-xs

Comment: пусть md ставит